# Laravel guard not working

Tags: php

I'm trying to implement admin/users login with laravel 5.5. I've created the Admin model, exactly the same as the user one, and set the guards for the admin. But during login, the guards are not being passed:

This is my AdminController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;


class AdminController extends Controller{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $guard = 'admin';

    public function showLoginForm(){
        return view('admin')->with(['title' => 'Panel de Administrador - Iniciar Sesión', 'bodyClass' => 'admin-view']);
    }
}
```

I tried to debug, and went into the vendor folder, to AuthenticatesUsers class, and debugged the request:

[image]

As you can see, it's using the User model and the web guard. Here's on the config file for the guards:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ]
],
```

and then I have the provider:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class
    ]
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I figured it out. Guard is not a property of the class, it's a function so I have to replace the inherited guard function, and use the Auth facade, like this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminController extends Controller{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    public function guard(){
        return Auth::guard('admin');
    }

    public function showLoginForm(){
        return view('admin')->with(['title' => 'Panel de Administrador - Iniciar Sesión', 'bodyClass' => 'admin-view']);
    }
}
```